# Select with specific attributes

Tags: php, mysql

Lets say we have 3 tables: products, attributes and details.

**products**

```
id name price
1  pr1  120
2  pr2  140
3  pr3  200
4  pr4  165
```

**attributes**

```
id name
1  color
2  guarantee
3  resolution
4  year
5  contrast ratio
```

**details**

```
id productId attributeId value
1  1         1           grey
2  1         2           yes
3  2         1           black
4  2         4           2011
5  2         5           70 000:1
6  4         2           no
```

And want for example to select all products with color = black, year = 2011 and contrast ratio = 70 000:1. In this example the result would be product with id = 2. What would be the mysql syntax for that?

```
SELECT * FROM products, details WHERE products.id = details.productId
AND details.attributeId = 1 (For the first attribute)
AND details.attributeId = 4 (For the second and third attribute?)
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
SELECT * 
FROM products p 
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM details d WHERE d.attributeId = 1 ) d1 ON p.ID = d1.productid 
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM details d WHERE d.attributeId = 4 ) d4 ON p.ID = d4.productid 
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM details d WHERE d.attributeId = 5 ) d5 ON p.ID = d5.productid 
WHERE 
d1.value = 'black' AND
d4.value = '2011' AND
d5.value = '70 000:1'
```

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know how to use JOIN.

Comment: you are welcome... please don't forget to upvote/mark as accepted any answer that was of help...